# How do I view my JSON data in a browser from my node.js VM Instance?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-compute-engine, postman

I currently have Google cloud Compute engine running nodejs that is connected to a Google Cloud SQL witch takes data from MySQL workbench. This is my server.js file that I run with 'node'

```
var gcloud = require("gcloud");
var express = require("express");
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  port: "3306",
  host : "173.194.87.72",
  user : "root",
  password : "****",
  database : "scripto_5_k"
});
var app = express();
/* Connection to Database */
connection.connect(function(error){
  if(error)
  {
    console.log("Problem with MySQL "+error);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Connected with Database ");
  }
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('hello index');
});

app.get('/load',function(req,res){
  console.log("/load hit");
  connection.query("SELECT * from user",function(err,rows){
    if(err)
    {
      console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
    }
    else
    {
      res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    }
  });
});
/*start the server */
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("its started on PORT %s", app.settings.port);
});
```

this should take all the data in the user table and put it to JSON when I use /load. But I cant get Postman to display the data. This is the address I have been using

```
http://130.211.90.249:3000/load
```

The address is from Google cloud the port is the one I set in the server.js file and /load should use the function I have written above.

Why am I not seeing a result with this input? I am running the server with 'node server.js' on my VM instance and it says I have successfully connected.

Any help is really appreciated.

**Edit 1**

This is what my VM looks like when I run the server.js

```
my_user_name@nodejs-2:~$ node server.js
its started on PORT 3000
Connected with Database
```

No error but in Postman I get "Could not get any response" when I put in the address given above.

**Edit 2**

Do I need to create a http server in the server.js file that I run so that the JSON object can be reached by the request in Postman?

**Edit 3**

If I follow the ip address of my google cloud VM it takes me to a default page for Bitnami but tells me that node js is running in the cloud. Do I need to remove this default page or is it fine to just leave whilst the server runs?

Here is a link http://130.211.90.249/

Comment: did your app output to the console any error?

Comment: Could you share your server.js code? it is hard to guess what else is happening since with your code your provided it is everything ok.

Comment: sure, I'll add it to the bit I already have up there.

Comment: console.log on /load route and see if the route is being reached, ensure your ip address is correct, try another port, by the way which version of express are you using?

Comment: I am using express 4.9.8.  I am using the IPv4 from the google cloud VM info on my instance and I can ping it. so how do I get the Console.log on route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81412/discussion-between-wilson-balderrama-and-arg0).

Comment: Do you have port 3000 exposed and firewall rule to open that port?

Comment: @JeffDeskins you're a god damn hero! I've been fighting with this all week. 
I added port 3000 to the fire wall and it let me through. just write up that port 3000 should be exposed through the fire wall so I can give you your bounty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the app is listening on port 3000 in your code, you need to create a firewall rule to make that port available from the outside.

From the developer console for that project, go to Networks and view the details for the default network.  Create a rule to allow traffic on port 3000.

Comment: wont let me award for 18hrs, I'll send it tomorrow. Thanks again for the help.